# How many 2200+ FIDE rated players are there?

Tags: fide, statistics, elo

Are there any sources for the recent numbers of players rated over 2200 byFIDE?

Answer (score 8):

According to [FIDE](https://ratings.fide.com), there are 20,763 players rated 2200 or above (as of May 2021). 9,460 are currently active

Comment: You might have added "Methodology" ;-) Click on "Advanced Search", which has quite a truckload of variables, rating interval being only one.